# Изменение расположения элементов View на разметке

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Мне необходимо изменять местоположение разных *view* (*textView*, *imageView*) внутри разметки *RelativeLayout* через Kotlin-код, работать это должно не только при нажатии кнопки.

Например, есть *imageView* с `id = "image"`, у которого размеры `width` и `height` устанавливаются внутри `onCreate()` в значение `size`. Так же он изначально привязан к нижнему и левому краям со значениями `100dp`. 
И я сдвигаю этот элемент вправо с помощью `image.x = size`. В итоге данное изображение сдвигается, однако выглядит это не лучшим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все примеры в интернете, которые я нашел, используются для Java-кода, и адаптировать его на Kotlin я не смог.
Кнопка сдвигается точно так же, макет находится в первоначальном месте, а сама кнопка сдвинута. Нажатие на макет ничего не вызывает, а нажатие на кнопку обрабатывается так, как должно.
Какие лучшие альтернативы этому способу?

Передвигать элемент нажатием на него не собираюсь, собираюсь передвигать его со временем и при нажатии разных кнопок, а так же при выполнении разных условий.

Comment: Что значит не смог? Любой Java код должен работать и на Kotlin. Самое банальное в Android Studio написать Java класс, нажать правой кнопкой мыши на него и нажать "Convert Java file to Kotlin file" и IDE сделает все за вас, а вам только поправить останется

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, у меня есть похожая вещь, давно на java писал. Там объект разметки, зажимаешь его и перетаскиваешь. Через `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)`. И там все приводится к `image.layoutParams`, из которых в Java доставался и изменялся `.leftMargin` и прочие. А вот после конверта в Kotlin код, это уже не работает, так как нету явного `view`, к которому применять метод, а указывать вместо `view` этот `image` - не работает.

Comment: @AnonimYs  попробуйте сделать отступы в XML: android:margin="100dp"       а потом вместо image.x изменяйте image.setmargin(.....)

Comment: Все верно было Java коде, элементы в контейнере и нужно двигать, меняя `layoutParams`. И никакой разницы нет, Kotlin это или Java, все это относится к Android framework и различия только синтаксические, принцип всегда один и тот же.

Comment: @Maks, в том то и дело, что нету сеттеров таких и такой код не работает

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, в layoutParams на Котлине не хранится margin, так я не могу изменить. Если же я применяю непосредственно `view.leftMargin = ...`, то меня посылает со словами `val cannot be reassigned`

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос с Java и Kotlin кодом. Все хранится одинаково и там и там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, по комментариям к вопросу и по ответу (который дан на JS, при вопросе заданном про Kotlin), все сводится к изменению `image.layoutParams`

Однако, данный способ не применим в Котлине:

```
var params = image.layoutParams
params.leftMargin = size // ошибка
image.layoutParams = params
```

Так как у класса `ViewGroup.LayoutParams!` нету свойства `leftMargin` (как и `marginLeft`, и всех остальных марджинов)

Решение данной проблемы - в том, какой именно класс мы используем. Решение следующее:

```
var params = image.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
params.leftMargin = size // никакой ошибки
image.layoutParams = params
```

И с классом `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` уже нет никаких проблем, и любой объект можно двигать по экрану без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Margin можно изменять програмно вот так:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, 
bottom);
yourimageview.setLayoutParams(params);
```